# Clamp rotation in all 3 axes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a rigidbody on my object and using mouse click and drag to rotate the object. How do I clamp all 3 axes between two angles?

```
public Rigidbody rb;

public void Update () {
  if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
    rotX = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * strength;
    rotY = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * strength;

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
      rotX = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
      rotY = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;
    }

    rb.AddTorque (rotY, -rotX, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are of course a couple of possible solutions. With the following code you can adjust the min/max rotation of your game object via the inspector.

After your *Update* function, in *LateUpdate*, we get the current rotation and eventually clamp it.

```
[SerializeField] private Vector3 maxRotation; // maximum rotation values for each axis
[SerializeField] private Vector3 minRotation; // minimum rotation values for each axis

private void LateUpdate()
{
    // get the current rotation of the GameObject
    Vector3 currentRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    // clamp the rotation values in each axis
    float clampedXRotation = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, minRotation.x, maxRotation.x);
    float clampedYRotation = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.y, minRotation.y, maxRotation.y);
    float clampedZRotation = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.z, minRotation.z, maxRotation.z);

    // create a new rotation based on the clamped values
    Quaternion clampedRotation = Quaternion.Euler(clampedXRotation, clampedYRotation, clampedZRotation);

    // apply the clamped rotation to the GameObject
    transform.rotation = clampedRotation;
}
```